# How to validate whole request is an array in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

I need to validate the JSON body of a request, and it must be an array.

I know I can validate individual fields as an array like so:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', 'array'],
]);
```

but how can I validate that the whole request is an array instead of, say, an object?

Comment: Why do you want to validate that everything is an array? simply when you send a request to a server you have to give a name to what you are sending. for example `name=John` `email=john@mail.com` if you want to send everything in an array it has to be `array[]=value1` `array[]=value2` and then in the backend `$request->array` and there validate that the `array parameter` is an `array`

Answer (score -1):

You can use Middleware to check raw request body.
`request()->all()` will always return array.

Comment: Do you mean to check if `$request->all()` returns an array? Because that `all()` will always return an array even if the request is an object.